# How to do_fetch by hand in a Yocto Project

Tags: yocto

My question is raised because my build-yocto server ran into the error:

```
ERROR: Fetcher failure: Fetch command failed with exit code 128, output:
Cloning into bare repository '/mnt/wd2tb/home/Work/skrzg1h_iWg21m_QtHmi/build/downloads/git2/github.com.qtproject.qtenginio.git'...    
Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://github.com/qtproject/qtenginio.git;name=qtenginio;branch=5.6;protocol=git'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
```

In the meantime, my PC can do that. So, I cloned the *qtenginio* repo to my local PC.

```
$ git clone git://github.com/qtproject/qtenginio.git;name=qtenginio;branch=5.6;protocol=git
```

And copy the downloaded source code above into the *downloads/git2/github.com.qtproject.qtenginio.git* folder of Yocto project.

Finally, I run the bitbake command.

```
$ bitbake qtenginio
```

But the fetch still fails.
Anyone can help me in this case ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Step 1: download the package by hand (**wget**, **git clone** ...)

Step 2: copy the package into *./build/downloads*

Step 3: touch a **package_name.done** file.

Step 4: change permission for the ***.done** file: **chmod 777 package_name.done**

Answer (score 12):

bitbake clones bare git repo, please add option '--bare' and touch a .done file to tell bitbake that do_fetch has been done already:

$ git clone --bare git://github.com/qtproject/qtenginio.git;name=qtenginio;branch=5.6 /mnt/wd2tb/home/Work/skrzg1h_iWg21m_QtHmi/build/downloads/git2/github.com.qtproject.qtenginio.git

$ touch /mnt/wd2tb/home/Work/skrzg1h_iWg21m_QtHmi/build/downloads/git2/github.com.qtproject.qtenginio.git.done

Comment: Hi 鹦鹉河, thanks for support. I tried you method. But, it didn't work. However, I tried to remove **#CONF_VERSION = '1'** in local.conf file and also did as your comment. It worked hereby.

Comment: It is a little weird that line begins with # in local.conf is a comment line and should NOT afftect anything.

Comment: 鹦鹉河, I meant **CONF_VERSION = '1'** changed to **#CONF_VERSION = '1'**

Comment: I am not sure why CONF_VERSION affect that. :(

Comment: Word of warning. If the `SRC_URI` says `;rev=`*name*, it will be trying to contact the server anyway (at least newer versions) to resolve it. Use a sha1 id to avoid that. Might work by removing it too.

Answer (score 0):

Some explanation about BitBake 'Fetch' git implementation : [Fetcher source code](https://github.com/openembedded/bitbake/blob/6abdc81dec06a362bfbcc06d69b90b96bd9bef01/lib/bb/fetch2/git.py#L5)

Firstly do '**git clone --bare --mirror**' of the remote repository (in first instance, bitbake fetcher is not a simple clone : [fetcher works by creating a bare clone of the remote](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/dev/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-fetching.html#git-fetcher-git))

Note a matching pattern to identify your *download/mirrortarball* name (download folder is defined by an environment variable DL_DIR)

line 5:

```
git fetcher support the SRC_URI with format of:
SRC_URI = "git://some.host/somepath;OptionA=xxx;OptionB=xxx;..."
```

Secondly, server host name 'some.host' and path 'somepath' are changed manually according to following rules, and then both are concatenated to become "gitsrcname"

line 262:

```
gitsrcname = '%s%s' % (ud.host.replace(':', '.'), ud.path.replace('/', '.').replace('*', '.').replace(' ','_'))
```

Thridly 'gitsrcname' is prefixed by 'git2_' and suffixed by '.tar.gz', to become your final mirror tarball file name.

line 279:

```
mirrortarball = 'git2_%s.tar.gz' % gitsrcname
```

Finally [create tarball](https://github.com/openembedded/bitbake/blob/6abdc81dec06a362bfbcc06d69b90b96bd9bef01/lib/bb/fetch2/git.py#L483), do a compressed archive (tar.gz) of the git bare repo, and paste it into DL_DIR.

Then [verify .donestamp](https://github.com/openembedded/bitbake/blob/6abdc81dec06a362bfbcc06d69b90b96bd9bef01/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py#L644), so add a tarball.done into DL_DIR.

Line 483:

```
runfetchcmd("touch %s.done" % ud.fullmirror, d)
```

During [git fetcher download stage](https://github.com/openembedded/bitbake/blob/6abdc81dec06a362bfbcc06d69b90b96bd9bef01/lib/bb/fetch2/git.py#L357), because fulltarball is found and destination actual clone dir is missing then your fulltarball will be used instead of a download.

line 357:

```
runfetchcmd("tar -xzf %s" % ud.fullmirror, d, workdir=ud.clonedir)
```