# Add specific header to bitbake wget fetcher

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I need to set a specific header to fetch an archive from a resource using the `wget` fetcher, analogous to:

```
wget --header "PRIVATE-ACCESS-TOKEN:blablablablabla https://some-resource...."
```

How can I set specific headers using that fetcher?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just came to my mind: Can I override the `do_fetch` and set the headers there? I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in various ways, here are some:

1. Download the file manually and place it in `downloads` folder, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058204/how-to-do-fetch-by-hand-in-a-yocto-project)
2. Override the `do_fetch` task:

```sh
do_fetch() {
    bbnote "Fetching some file ..."
    wget ...
}
```

But you need to take note that `do_unpack` uses `SRC_URI`, so you still gonna need to specify `SRC_URI` to the file URL for the unpack, example that I test with `wget` package itself:

```sh
LICENSE="CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget2-2.0.0.tar.gz"

do_fetch(){
    bbwarn "Fetching wget"
    wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget2-2.0.0.tar.gz
}
```

After running `do_fetch` the file gets downloaded in `downloads` and then `do_unpack` unpacked it under `WORKDIR` of the recipe.

3. Specify your own `wget` command line for the `wget` fetcher:

```
FETCHCMD_wget = "/usr/bin/env wget --header "PRIVATE-ACCESS-TOKEN:blablablablabla""
```

the default `wget` command is present in: `poky/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/wget.py`:

```
self.basecmd = d.getVar("FETCHCMD_wget") or "/usr/bin/env wget -t 2 -T 30 --passive-ftp --no-check-certificate"
```

For more information check: this [link](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0.2/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#http-ftp-fetcher).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have to define `--download-document=${SOMEPATH}/${PN}.zip` because otherwise wget stores it under some name deduced from a part of the url. I don't manage to automatically unpack that package. I tried setting `${SOMEPATH}` to `${WORLKDIR}` and to `${DL_DIR}`. The target is stored as expected but the zip file doesn't get unpacked. A hint here would be very much appreciated.