# How to unpack a zip file in bitbakes do_unpack method

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

This is basically a follow-up from this thread: [Add specific header to bitbake wget fetcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71769720/add-specific-header-to-bitbake-wget-fetcher/71771071#71771071)

I override `do_fetch` to set a specific header and store the archive in `${DL_DIR}/${PN}.zip`. The `do_unpack` job doesn't unpack that archive automatically. So I override `do_unpack` as follows:

```
do_unpack () {
    bbnote "unpacking"
    unzip -q -o ${DL_DIR}/${PN}.zip -d ${S}
}
```

If I execute: `bitbake my_recipe` bitbake complains that it can't find `unzip`:

```
run.do_unpack.20659: unzip: not found
```

I have `DEPENDS = "unzip-native"` in my recipe.

Thanks again a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a mixture of two problems:

1. It has to be `do_fetch[depends] += "unzip-native:do_populate_sysroot"` , not `DEPENDS = "unzip-native"`
2. The call to `unzip` has to be: `${bindir}/env unzip`